# Prototype: Selecting an element with multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

I have that element:

```
<span class="class1 class2">...</span>
```

How can I select this elmement using both classes with Prototype JS? Like this maybe?

```
$$(span.class1.class2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, you just forgot to put it in a string:

```
$$('span.class1.class2')
```

Comment: Also FYI the `$$()` method returns an array of elements, if there is only one element you want to select `$$('span.class1.class2').first()` or `$$('span.class1.class2')[0]` will get the element for you. Otherwise you can use the Enumerable http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/ methods to iterate through the array

Answer (score 0):

you also have native browser support:

```
document.querySelector('span.class1.class2')
```

which is faster then using any other wrapper.